# How to Yield Results Javascript Nested Deferreds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dojo, deferred

I am using the ESRI Javascript API to retrieve all records in a dataset in ArcGIS Server for client side processing.  The server limits each response to 1000 records.  This means I have to keep track of my features as they are retrieved and then retrieve the next batch.  The call to the API that retrieved records returns a `dojo/Deferred` object.

I'd like to be able to retrieve a batch of 1000 records, process them, and save them back to the dataset all in sequence.  Meanwhile, as soon as a batch of records is retrieved from the dataset, the next batch would begin being retrieved.

I've done something similar using recursive function calls and saving the resulting `dojo/Deferred`'s to a list to later process with `dojo/promise/all`.  However, this means processing all features at once when they have all been retrieved.  I'd rather be able to process each batch individually as they are retrieved.

My app uses `dojo` with the ESRI API and jQuery/jQuery Mobile.

Here is my code that returns all features at once:

```
//layer = dataset (geographic data)
//count = count of records (features) in dataset
//objectIds = list of all unique record ID's in dataset.  This can be retrieved from the server and is not limited by the 1000 record limit
//Query = ESRI API Query Task used to retrieve features from the dataset

if (count > layer.maxRecordCount) {

    var features = [];

    var i = 0;

    var deferreds = [];
    for (i; i < objectIds.length; i += layer.maxRecordCount) {

        var q = new Query();
        q.objectIds = objectIds.slice(i, i + layer.maxRecordCount);

        var deferred;
        if (select) { deferred = layer.selectFeatures(q, selectionType); }
        else { deferred = layer.queryFeatures(q); }

        deferreds.push(deferred);

    }

    var deferred = all(deferreds).then(function(featuresets) {

        var featureLists = array.map(featuresets, function(featureset) {
            return featureset.features || featureset;
        });

        var features = [].concat.apply([], featureLists);

        return features;

    });

    return deferred;

}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've figured out a way to accomplish what I want using an `Array` as a `queue`.

Here is the function to retrieve records from the database:

```
getAllFeatures : function(layer, returnGeometry, fields) {

    var queue = ["start"];

    var q = new esriQuery();
    q.where = "1=1";

    var qt = new QueryTask(layer.url);

    layer.queryIds(q).then(function(objectIds) {

        var deferreds = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < objectIds.length; i += layer.maxRecordCount) {

            var q = new esriQuery();
            q.objectIds = objectIds.slice(i, i + layer.maxRecordCount);
            q.returnGeometry = !!returnGeometry;
            q.outFields = fields && [layer.objectIdField].concat(fields) || ["*"];

            deferreds.push(qt.execute(q).then(function(featureSet) {
                queue.push(featureSet.features);
            }));

        }

        all(deferreds).then(function() {
            queue.push("stop");
        });

    });

    return queue;

}
```

and here is the code that processes the data:

```
var queue = pgUtils.getAllFeatures(layer, false, [priorityField.name]);

var features = queue.shift();

var interval;

if (features === "start") {

    interval = setInterval(function() {
        features = queue.shift();
        if (features && features instanceof Array) {
            self._prioritize(features, formData);
            new esriRequest({
                url : layer.url + "/applyEdits",
                content : {
                    f : "json",
                    updates : JSON.stringify(features)
                }
            }, {usePost : true});
        } else if (features === "stop") {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

As you can see, I use the `Array` named `queue` to push individual responses in the `getAllFeatures` function and I use `setInterval` to retrieve those responses from `queue` until the `"stop"` signal is found.  So far, this seems to be working with my test dataset of 450 records.  I'm not sure how this would work for larger datasets yet.  I'm definitely open to any suggestions for a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the DeferredList.

```
var def_array = [];
for(..) {
  var def = new Deferred();
   ...
  def_array.push(def);
}
new DeferredList(def_array).then(function(res){
   ...
   //this runs only all the deferreds in the def_array is invoked and completed
});
```

DeferredList has many other params/flags, which are for specific purposes, based on requirements. But, for your case, i guess, the above solution is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  In dojo 1.9 `DeferredList` is deprecated.  Instead, they suggest using `dojo/promise/all`, which is what I use in my code posted above.  Unfortunately, whether I use `all` or `DeferredList`, it means waiting until all batches are complete and then finishing processing.  I am trying to process on batch at a time independently of other batches.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you want to essentially request batches serially rather than in parallel, processing each as it comes in before requesting the next.  As you've noted, `all` really lends itself to parallel processing though.  You'd need a different approach to do what you want (note I have no way of testing this so it might still need some work):

```
var i = 0,
    len = objectIds.length,
    features = [];

function requestNext() {
    var q = new Query(),
        promise;

    q.objectIds = objectIds.slice(i, i + layer.maxRecordCount);
    promise = select ? layer.selectFeatures(q, selectionType) :
        layer.queryFeatures(q);

    return promise.then(function (featureset) {
        // Add the latest set of results to the features array
        features = features.concat(featureset.features || featureset);

        // If there are more objects to query, call this function again,
        // chaining the subsequent request's resolution to this promise;
        // otherwise, return the built features array
        i += layer.maxRecordCount;
        return i < len ? requestNext() : features;
    });
}

return requestNext();
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to do everything in parallel.  Currently, the function I posted submits multiple `Query` requests to the server, but then waits for all responses before returning any features by using `all`.  I am looking for a function that sends the requests in parallel and returns the response in parallel.